# pandas how do i merge similar columns name together?

Tags: python, pandas

Hi all I have been trying to convert this DataFrame

```
col_a_1  col_a_2  col_b_1 col_b_2  col_c_1  col_c_2 col_a_3  col_a_4  col_b_3 col_b_4  col_c_3  col_c_4
 itema    $1xx      itemb    $2xx    itemc     $3xx   NaN        NaN      NaN     NaN       NaN    NaN
 itema    $1xx      itemb    $2xx    itemc     $3xx   NaN        NaN      NaN     NaN       NaN    NaN
   .       .          .        .        .       .      .          .         .      .          .     .
   .       .          .        .        .       .      .          .         .      .          .     .
   .       .          .        .        .       .      .          .         .      .          .     .
   NaN     NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN     NaN    itema     $1xx     itemb     $2xx    itemc    $3xx
```

to this output:

```
 col_a_1  col_a_2  col_b_1 col_b_2  col_c_1  col_c_2 
     itema    $1xx      itemb    $2xx    itemc     $3xx  
     itema    $1xx      itemb    $2xx    itemc     $3xx   
       .       .          .        .        .       .      
       .       .          .        .        .       .      
       .       .          .        .        .       .      
     itema     $1xx     itemb     $2xx    itemc   $3xx
```

how do shift drop the column "col_a_3,col_a_4,col_b_3,col_b_4,col_c_3,col_c_4" and shift the data to corresponse with"col_a_1,col_a_2,col_b_1,col_b_2 ,col_c_1,col_c_2" respectively

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to move the value of say `col_a_3` to `col_a_1` if value is not NaN, similarly, move value of `col_a_4` to `col_a_2` if value is not NaN. Is that correct understanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use merge method with inplace =True after that, use drop function to remove the col_a_3,col_a_4,col_b_3,col_b_4,col_c_3,col_c_4